# Firebase What will happen to the old codes

Tags: ios, firebase

After Firebase's new update my app is still running with the old code. What will happen to my app? Is there a deadline to change the old code to the new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are fine at least for some time. But I suggest you to update your code since they have now new features and all are packed together.
Check out their new [website](https://firebase.google.com) also. Here you can see how to upgrade: https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/

Comment: Because I'll be busy for couple of weeks you know that's way I'm concern

Comment: @Rioodi Understandable. In this time nothing gonna happen. You can sleep in peace, your app is fine :)

Comment: Tanks Tarvo for the help I appreciate that

Answer (score 1):

*Firebaser here*

While it's great that you're eager to update your app to the new Firebase features, there is no need to rush that. The existing Firebase APIs will remain functional for quite some time.

Have a look at our [upgrade guide for iOS apps](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-ios) to learn more. It details the steps to update your app either to the new console (and pricing plans) and (potentially) later the new SDKs. If you find something that isn't covered, just post a question.